# New IOS5 UISwitch doesn't look disabled in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uiswitch, ios5

I'm placing a `UISwitch`es in `UITableViewCell`s and I try to disable it initially:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    self.switch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    self.switch.enabled = NO;
    cell.accessoryView = self.switch;
    ...
}
```

In IOS versions prior to IOS5, the (old-looking) switch is disabled and also looks disabled (dimmed) when the view appears.

In IOS5 the (new-looking) switch is disabled alright, I can't flip it, but it does not look disabled at this stage. It has the same brightness as an enabled switch.

If I enable and re-disable it later in the code (NOT in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` callback), it does look disabled (dimmed).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in IOS5?

Comment: Don't use `switch` as the switch's name, it's a reserved word in Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, UISwitch's designated initializer is `-initWithFrame:` — have you tried using that?

Comment: Yes I did initially, it didn't solve the problem. I changed it to simple init because cell.accessoryView sets the frame anyhow and I hoped that using a simple init would provide a solution.

Comment: Even if it doesn't help here, I'd use the designated initializer. (Which ignores part of the frame too…)

Comment: Bypassing the designated initializer may result in an improperly initialized object, which _will_ get you into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I faced up same problem with iOS 5. You can use `-initWithFrame` to create switch and then you can add the switch as a subview of cell contentView and (not an accesoryview and do not forget to count subviews of contentView, otherwise you could add a new uiswitch) with `-addSubview:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by saving all my UISwitches in an array.

Then on my **viewDidAppear**, I iterate through the array disabling them.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    for (UISwitch *switchView in switchMArray) {
        switchView.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```